# How to paint through a whole mesh while weight painting

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

Is there a way to paint through a mesh while weight painting? I have clicked the "limit selection to visible" button, but I still cannot paint through all visible faces in wireframe mode.

Comment: Make sure *Limit selection* is **off**. It should work.

Comment: @iKlsR As mentioned in my question, the limit selection is most definitely off.

Comment: People often confuse the toggled states, can you share your file.

Comment: The toggled states? What is that? Can you please explain.

Comment: @KeshaWilson Actually I think they are painted, but you can't see it from this point, if you rotate the view to look you see it is actually painted. It doesn't matter whether you are in wireframe mode or solid mode, since the only difference are the edges that are displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Disable*** the ***Limit selection to visible*** option as people suggested you in their comments. Make sure, that the icon ***is not highlighted***.
[image]
[image]

Also make sure, that you haven't masked some part of your object. Select the whole mesh before painting (<kbd>A</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: Thank you! The reason why it didn't work was because the whole mesh wasn't selected.